# Conda ModuleNotFoundError while trying to install Plotly

Tags: plotly, conda

I am having issues trying to install the plotly package.

To reproduce the problem:

1 - Install Anaconda:

```
pyenv install anaconda3-5.3.1
pyenv local anaconda3-5.3.1
```

2 - Install plotly as per the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/):

```
conda install -c plotly plotly=4.5.0
conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"
```

After running the second `conda` command, I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/naok/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.3.1/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: System info? Windows?

Comment: Depending on your system, this might just be an [issue with conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9507) `4.8`

Comment: Why are you using pyenv to install conda? Why not install a regular version of anaconda or miniconda and use it instead of pyenv to start with?